# EF COdeFirst Table Per Type setup with list reference to the base class

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, table-per-type

i am setting up the ef code first with table per type. See the following structure. The idea is to store inherited class information in its own table and at the same time a derived class can have reference to a parent and a list of children that also derive from the BaseClass.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
}

public class A_Class : BaseClass
{
     public string A_Property {get;set;}
     public BaseClass Parent {get; set;}
     public IList<BaseClass> Children { get; set; }
}

public class B_Class : BaseClass
{
     public string B_Property {get;set;}
     public BaseClass Parent {get; set;}
     public IList<BaseClass> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea how to setup the DbContext for the model?

Comment: is there any problem with the usual way to do it?

Comment: it actually works, i was getting some weird error. But the default model add column for each type of baseclass in the BaseClass table, is there a way to change that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

To generate the 3 tables you can use the API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseClass>().ToTable("BaseClass");
    modelBuilder.Entity<A_Class>().ToTable("AClass");
    modelBuilder.Entity<B_Class>().ToTable("BClass");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

or the `TableAttribute`:

```
[Table("BaseClass")]
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
}

[Table("AClass")]
public class A_Class : BaseClass
{
    public string A_Property { get; set; }
    public BaseClass Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BaseClass> Children { get; set; }
}

[Table("BClass")]
public class B_Class : BaseClass
{
    public string B_Property { get; set; }
    public BaseClass Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BaseClass> Children { get; set; }
}
```